# How to check what remote access software/services are installed?

Tags: privacy

Is there any easy way (a program/app would probably be the best, but I don't think I'm allowed to ask for a recommendation on one [if one even exist] on these sites) to check whether any known remote access programs are installed on a computer (PC, Mac, Linux, etc.)?  This would include things like LogMein, GoToMyPC, TeamViewer, ScreenConnect, RDP enabled, etc.

As an IT consultant, I'm often in the position of taking over support of new systems that have previously been supported by others (and who knows what has previously gone on with these systems prior to my arrival).  As a result, securing them is a good first step, but since many IT firms use different remote access software (which might not always appear in the system tray, start menu, or add/remove programs), I thought some way to quickly assess the computer's remote access vulnerabilities and disable/remove them would be a useful thing to do.

Thanks!

Comment: On a local computer? With what permissions?

Comment: Yup, on a local computer, with admin privileges.

Comment: The first things I would look for are Programs: Anything that seems like a remoting program. Check the Firewall: Usually applications that want to connect remotely will need an exception in the firewall. And searching the processes. Most remote programs will start up with the computer so the best way would be to analyze the processes"linux,Windows, and Mac" in my opinion. Im sure there may be a script you could right after finding a lot of common ones to automatically look for them.